# How do I associate various key names to an ec2 instance in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In the `aws_instance` resource in Terraform, there is the possibility to associate a Key Pair to the ec2 instance through:

`key_name = "deployment-key"`

That's fine and it works well. But I need to associate more than one key to an instance.

When I try to use `key_name` several times it fails with:

`The argument "key_name" was already set at instance-main.tf:13,3-11. Each argument may be set only once.`

How can I set several key pairs to an instance?

Comment: Well, you really only need one. When you log in you can add more.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE for your comment. Although, the whole point of infrastructure as code is to avoid doing things manually.

Comment: But it wasn't meant to be used that way . If you can add only one key as per the API, how do you plan on adding more than one?

Comment: You could use a User Data script to run arbitrary code, such as adding more keys. Or, preferably, connect the instance to the corporate AD/LDAP system to have proper centralized access controls.

Comment: @MarkoE that sorts of answer my question then, if it's not meant to be used that way then I guess I can't.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, there is no AD/LDAP in this case it's for a specific developer and for the build system. I'll have a look at what I can do with a User Data script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you question what I understood is you want to associate multiple keys for a single instance. If yes, then it's not possible, the key you mention in terraform config file is for login purpose, so one key should be assigned for login. If you need to add more key, then either you can use user-data or add by logging into the instance manually.

Better to do such of things using 'shell' module in Packer, so that it will be hardened in OS image and don't have to do this things repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this using [templatefiles](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.2.x/functions/templatefile).

### Single extra key

Here's a tested snippet where I add a second key to an instance.

```
data "aws_key_pair" "key_pair" {
  key_name           = "key_owner_1"
  include_public_key = true
}

data "aws_key_pair" "extra_key_pair" {
  key_name           = "key_owner_2"
  include_public_key = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = "t3.micro"
  key_name                    = data.aws_key_pair.key_pair.key_name
  
  user_data                   = templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.sh", {
    extra_key = data.aws_key_pair.extra_key_pair.public_key
  })
}
```

in `user_data.sh`

```bash
echo -e "\n${extra_key}" >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

### Templatefiles & lists

I haven't tested this personally but templatefiles support lists (cf. [their doc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.2.x/functions/templatefile)). Something like this should work:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.sh", { ssh_keys = ["key_string_1", "key_string_2"] })
```

in `user_data.sh`

```bash
%{ for key in ssh_keys ~}
echo -e "\n${key}" >> >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
%{ endfor ~}
```

The syntax here might be inexact, please correct it in the comments I will include it here.

Good luck with your issue !

Here's the ubuntu ami missing from the above snippet

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}
```